# Convert string to float

Tags: c, string, floating-point, microcontroller

I'm programming on a AVR XMEGA microcontroller, using AtmelStudio.

I'm having trouble converting a string to a float. The string is called `token2` and has the value `"8.604165"`

I've already tried a couple of functions:

- `float lon = atof(token2); printf("lon=%f", lon);` returns `lon=?`
- `float lon = strtod(token2, NULL); printf("lon=%f", lon);` returns `lon=?`
- `float lon = strtof(token2, NULL); printf("lon=%f", lon);` gives an error `undefined reference to strtof`, even including `<stdlib.h>`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your code can be fine: [look at this example](http://ideone.com/azrwwH)

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Are you writing some code for microcontroller? If so, please specify the environment. Might be related: [c - Arduino: printf/fprintf prints question mark instead of float - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146850/arduino-printf-fprintf-prints-question-mark-instead-of-float)

Comment: Yes @MikeCAT. I'm programming on a AVR XMega microcontroller

Comment: Looks like your problem is with `printf`, not with the conversion. Try `printf("lon=%f", 8.604165);`, and tell us what you see. BTW, in the third bullet, I wouldn't describe it as '**returns an error**' since there's no "return" here (it's a compilation error, not a runtime error).

Comment: In addition, please use a debugger and tell us what is the value of `lon` after calling `atof` and after calling `strtod`.

Comment: does the code have the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`?  Is the code being compiled with one fo these defined: ` _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600 || _ISOC99_SOURCE ||
           _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L;
           or cc -std=c99`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is something specific of microcontrollers.

Similar to what @Sneftel said, I just had to add the libraries `libprintf_flt.a` and `libm.a` in AtmelStudio.

Comment: It's not just specific to this IDE, this approach is fairly common with smaller microcontrollers as processing floats adds quite a bit of bloat to your code size for space constrained devices.  In some devices floating point math is absent completely, others it's an linker option to vary the included version.

Answer (score 6):

By default, AVR-libc tries to save space in the binary by not linking in floating-point-related stuff. For functions like `atof` that's easy because if you don't call them then the linker won't include them. For `printf`, though, the linker can't tell whether you're planning on using it for floating-point numbers.

Instead, AVR-libc has multiple libraries which define `printf`. The `printf` in the default library has full functionality except that it doesn't support floating-point numbers. If you want to save space in your binary and you're not using the more advanced features of `printf` (namely format flags), you can link with `printf_min` to replace that with a teenier version. And if you want to print floating-point numbers, you need the full powered version defined in `printf_flt`.

[This page](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__stdio_1gaa3b98c0d17b35642c0f3e4649092b9f1.html) describes the proper linker options to select those alternative versions. In short, add `-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt -lm` to your linker options.